# Как сказать YamlDotNet, что бы он читал дату в русском формате?

Tags: c#

Читаю настройки из YAML файла. В настройках присутствует InitialDateTime.

В моем случае она задан как 07.09.2020 9:00:00.

Система вычитывает дату как 9 июля, а мине надо сказать YamlDotNet, что это 7 сентября.

Подскажите как дать понять ей, что дата записана как день.месяц.год.

Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace YamlDotNet_stackoverflow_Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var settings = Settings.GetFromYamlFile("Settings.yaml");
            settings.SaveToYamlFile("Settings_output.yaml");
        Console.WriteLine($"{settings.InitialDateTime:U}");
        }
    }
}
```

Settings.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization;

namespace YamlDotNet_stackoverflow_Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Настройки расчета солвера
    /// </summary>
    public class Settings
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Начальная дата-время
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime InitialDateTime { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Чтение настроек из yaml-файла
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Settings GetFromYamlFile(string fileName)
        {
            //CreateYamlFile(fileName);
            var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder()
                .IgnoreUnmatchedProperties().Build();
            using var file = new StreamReader(fileName);
            var res = deserializer.Deserialize<Settings>(file);
            return res;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Сохранение настроек в yaml-файл
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void SaveToYamlFile(string fileName)
        {
            var builder = new SerializerBuilder();
            builder = builder.EmitDefaults(); // Для принудительной сериализации 0-вых значений
            var serializer = builder.Build();
            using var file = new StreamWriter(fileName);
            serializer.Serialize(file, this);
            file.Flush();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Генератор для трафарета yaml-файла настроек при изменении структуры класса настроек
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName"></param>
        private static void CreateYamlFile(string fileName)
        {
            var builder = new SerializerBuilder();
            builder.EmitDefaults(); // Для принудительной сериализации 0 значений
            var serializer = builder.Build();
            var settings = new Settings
            {
                InitialDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 9, 7, 9, 0, 0)
            };
            using var file = new StreamWriter(fileName);
            serializer.Serialize(file, settings);
            file.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Settings.yaml

```
InitialDateTime: 07.09.2020 9:00:00
```

Пример данных и код: https://github.com/Dejsving/YamlDotNet-stackoverflow-Example

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы добавили код для воспроизведения проблемы и сэмпл данных.

Comment: [WithTypeConverter](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/wiki/Serialization.Deserializer#withtypeconverteriyamltypeconverter) + [DateTimeConverter](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/blob/master/YamlDotNet/Serialization/Converters/DateTimeConverter.cs)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а подробнее расписать можете? Замена конвертера у них есть, но страницы с примерами нет. А второй файл - это я так понял из исходника.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить к сериализатору конвертер [DateTimeConverter](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/blob/master/YamlDotNet/Serialization/Converters/DateTimeConverter.cs) с помощью метода [WithTypeConverter](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/wiki/Serialization.Deserializer#withtypeconverteriyamltypeconverter).

```
var converter = new DateTimeConverter(provider: new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));

var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder()
    .IgnoreUnmatchedProperties()
    .WithTypeConverter(converter)
    .Build();
```

В конвертере можно задать как провайдер (в примере выше это русскоязычная культура `new CultureInfo("ru-RU")`), так и формат:

```
var converter = new DateTimeConverter(formats: "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss");
```

Форматов можно указать несколько, сработает первый успешный.
Документация [Custom date and time format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Можно комбинировать провайдер и форматы.

---

Дополнительно откройте пространства имён:

```
using System.Globalization;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization.Converters;
```

---

Примечание: метод `EmitDefaults` является устаревшим. Возможно, вы используете старую версию библиотеки. Советую обновиться.
Мне интеллисенс подсказывает заменить его на `ConfigureDefaultValuesHandling`:

```
builder.ConfigureDefaultValuesHandling(DefaultValuesHandling.Preserve);
```

Comment: Выяснил интересную особенность - видимо YamlDotNet.Core не доработан или я не так понял логику YamlDotNet и YamlDotNet.Core это реально ядро, а не переделка под .Net Core. Так как пробовал все вышеперечисленное много раз на YamlDotNet.Core (у меня она стояла - версия 1.0.0) и там этого функционала просто нет. ConfigureDefaultValuesHandling тоже нет - IDE не видит ее, и решарпер не знает так же

Comment: Последняя версия YamlDotNet.NetCore вышла в 2016 году. Определённо, это устаревшая версия. Нужно пользоваться YamlDotNet.